# Passing Parameter for Queryset to Django Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am using a django (2.1) ModelMultipleChoice field for a form. I am trying to modify the queryset based on the slug in the URL. I am pretty certain I am missing something stupid.

The Form:

```
class SubdomainForm(forms.Form):
    # TODO Get the value slug from init
    slug = "camp" # Works well if value of slug set here.
    q = Feature2Subdomain.objects.all().select_related().filter(subdomain__slug=slug)
    choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset = q,
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    slug = kwargs.pop('slug', None) # Correctly obtains slug from url
    super(SubdomainForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

The View:

```
class SubdomainDetailView(FormView):
    template_name = "guide/subdomain-detail.html"
    form_class = SubdomainForm

    def get_form_kwargs(self, form_class=SubdomainForm):
        s = dict(slug = self.kwargs['slug'])
        return s
```

URLS.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('subdomain/<slug:slug>/',
         SubdomainDetailView.as_view(),
         name="subdomain-detail"
    ),
    .....
```

Obviously, the idea is that the slug from the URL is used to modify the queryset. (in the example the value of the slug is "camp"

I can obtain the value of the slug in the **init** method for the form, and can call super() to instantiate the form. However, I can't figure out how to access the value in the "choices" line of the form. If I hard code the value of slug="camp" I can get the whole thing to work properly.

I've been working on this for a couple of days and have exhausted all the examples in SO and on google.

I tried moving the "choices" assignment into the **init** method and using

```
 self.choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset = Feature2Subdomain.objects.all().select_related().filter(subdomain__slug=slug)
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )
```

But this is not then displaying the correct response (it returns an empty form)

Also tried assigning the queryset in the **init** method like this.

```
class SubdomainForm(forms.Form):
    choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = kwargs.pop('slug', None) # Correctly obtains slug from url
        self.queryset = Feature2Subdomain.objects.all().select_related().filter(subdomain__slug=slug)

        super(SubdomainForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

I then get the error: 
TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'

Feeling quite lost on where to go next.

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your last attempt, you can modify the code like this:

```
class SubdomainForm(forms.Form):
    choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset = Feature2Subdomain.objects.all()
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = kwargs.pop('slug', None) # Correctly obtains slug from url
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) 
        self.fields['choices'].queryset = Feature2Subdomain.objects.filter(subdomain__slug=slug)  # you don't need select related
```

Comment: Got it. I need to declare a queryset in the form definition, but this is over-ridden by the __init__ method.